# What is the difference between a UML node and a UML component?

Tags: uml, apple-watch

I am designing an UML diagram for an Apple Watch Extension. How should I represent host app using UML ? UML Node or UML component ? Please note that there can be inter app communication between the extension app and the iPhone app (host app).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UML nodes are apparently used to depict physical resources, so your watch would be a node, whereas a component is usually understood as a *software* component. Since you want to model software, go with components (which will also nicely visualise the plugging between extension and host).

Answer (score 1):

`uml-diagrams.org` explains the basic difference as ["**node** is a deployment target"](http://www.uml-diagrams.org/deployment-diagrams.html#node) while ["**component** is a structured class representing a modular part of a system"](http://www.uml-diagrams.org/component-diagrams.html#component)

They're typically used in **different kinds of diagrams** with different purposes. e.g. in `UML Class Diagram` both extension app and iPhone app would be represented as `UML Class`

You can, however, create your custom diagram mixing whatever `UML` artifacts you need - to make your design message clear to the readers

Comment: I support the last statement: feel free to use UML in a way that you can communicate.

Answer (score 0):

-Node represent the physical part of the system. for instance , server ,network and printer etc.

-Component represent any part of the system it might be physical aspect such as libraries ,file ,executables,document,packages etc  that reside on the node.

-Component - refers to a module of classes that represent independent systems or subsystems with the ability to interface with the rest of the system.so it tells who does the system functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Components are things that participate in the execution of a system; nodes are things that execute components.
Components represent the physical packaging of logical elements; nodes
represent the physical deployment of components.